# How to get the output from arrow & curry function in javascript

Tags: ecmascript-6, currying, arrow-functions

Here is my code. I did not get the output that I want. It should hand over 50 but it does'nt. Someone please help me to fix the bug?

```
const checkNum = entity => typeof entity === 'string' ? parseInt(entity) : entity;
const multiply = (x , y) => x => y => x * y;
const multiOne = (ar, gr) => ar.map(checkNum).map(multiply);
multiOne([5, 10]);
```

Comment: You want `.reduce(multiply, 1)`, or possibly `multiply(...ar.map(checkNum))` in this specific case of passing a tuple (`ar.length == 2`).

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` is a one-to-one operation, so for your array it produces another array. The second argument is not what you think it is.

`reduce` is a many-to-one operation, taking and array and reducing / folding it by repeatedly applying an operation to two elements at a time (two elements from the array at first, then the result of the previous operation combined with another element of the array).

```js
const multiply = (x, y) => x * y;
const multiOne = (ar) => ar.reduce(multiply);
console.log(multiOne([5, 10]));
```

You also seem to want partially applied function, but you are currying too much. The standard functions in ES6 don't use currying a lot, it is more common in actual FP languages (e.g. Haskell).